# Changing repeated letters in a String

Tags: java, eclipse, string

I have to write a method that anytime two of the same letters are next to each other both letters will be replaced by whatever the next letter in the word is.If the last two letters of the word are the same then the letters should just be removed. For example "wheel"should become "whlll". However, nothing should happen to the new repeated letters. For example, "keeper" should print "kppper"

Here was my attempt:

```
public String change(String s){
    if(s.length()>=2&&s.substring(s.length()-2,s.length()-1).equals(s.substring(s.length()-1)))
        s=s.substring(0,s.length()-2);
    if(s.length()<2)
        return s;
    String f="";
    for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++){
        if(i+1<s.length()-1&&s.substring(i,i+1).equals(s.substring(i+1,i+2))){
            if(s.length()<4){
                f=f+s.substring(s.length()-i)+s.substring(s.length()-1);
                i=i+2;}
            else{f=f+s.substring(i+2,i+3)+s.substring(i+2,i+3);
            i=i+2;}
        }
        else {
            f=f+s.substring(i,i+1);
        }

    }
    if(f.length()<s.length())
        f=f+s.substring(s.length()-1);
    return f;
}
```

However, the method only works if the word doesn't continue after the non-repeated letter. For example "keep", "wheel". If I try adding endings or more repeated letters it doesn't give the correct output. "foodloop" prints "fddlppp" there's one "d" missing, and "missing" prints "miiingg"one "i" missing and an extra "g"

Comment: First you should add some proper spacing around operators, and also some indentation adjustments...

Comment: @shmosel it would just print "b"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how your code should look like :

```
public static String change(String s){
    if(s.length()>=2&&s.substring(s.length()-2,s.length()-1).equals(s.substring(s.length()-1)))
        s=s.substring(0,s.length()-2);
    if(s.length()<2)
        return s;
    String f="";

    for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++){
        if((i+1<s.length()-1)&& (s.substring(i,i+1).equals(s.substring(i+1,i+2)))){
            if(s.length()<4){
                f=f+s.substring(s.length()-i)+s.substring(s.length()-1);
                i=i+2;
             }
            else{
              f=f+s.substring(i+2,i+3)+s.substring(i+2,i+3);
              i=i+1;
              }
        }
        else {
            f=f+s.substring(i,i+1);
        }

    }
    if(f.length()<s.length())
        f=f+s.substring(s.length()-1);
    return f;
}
```

Here I changed your code from :

```
   else{
      f=f+s.substring(i+2,i+3)+s.substring(i+2,i+3);
      i=i+2;
   }
```

to :

```
else{
    f=f+s.substring(i+2,i+3)+s.substring(i+2,i+3);
    i=i+1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't *directly* address the question. And it doesn't deal with certain details that weren't specified (e.g. whitespace, uppercase, triples). But... regex right?

```
public String change(String s) {
    return s.replaceAll("([a-z])\\1([a-z])", "$2$2$2");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code is very hard to understand. Here I have attached a code which will take input from console just a single word and will replace any char if they appears two consecutive times.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TwoRepeatedLetter {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        String word;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        while(sc.hasNext()){
        word=sc.next();
        getRepeatedReplaced(word);
        }
        sc.close();

    }

    public static void getRepeatedReplaced(String s){
        String result="";
        if(s.length()<2)
            result=s;
        if(s.charAt(s.length()-2)==s.charAt(s.length()-1))
        {
            result=s.substring(0,s.length()-2);
            s=result;
        }
        char []saschar=s.toCharArray();
        for(int i=1;i<s.length();i++){

            if(saschar[i-1]==saschar[i]){
                saschar[i-1]=saschar[i+1];
                saschar[i]=saschar[i+1];
                i=i+2;
            }


        }

        System.out.println(String.valueOf(saschar));
    }
}
```

Some input and output are as follows

- toop tppp
- loop lppp
- looooop loooppp
- wheel whlll
- chuul chlll